# How to create a combination of features using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Hello everyone I am trying to achieve this according to the docstring using chain,combinations_with_replacement from itertools.

```
data = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

data.uptodegree(2)

output = np.array([[1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4, 9, 12,16]])
```

Basically the calculations are 1, 1^1, 2^1, 1^2, 1^1 * 2^1, 2^2. With the first one just being included by default. I am not sure how to go about this at all. The last part is another example of how these numbers are calculated.

$$\phi_{degree}(x_i) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & w_i & z_i & w_iz_i & w_i^2z_i & w_iz_i^2 & \dots & w_iz_i^{degree-1} & w_i^{degree} & z_i^{degree} \end{bmatrix} $$\n

Comment: Can you show us your attempt please?

Comment: I don't know how to even begin. All I've thought of doing is taking combinations_with_replacement of the first array and then for each combination it returns raise it to a power. aka (1, 1) (1,2) (2,2)

Comment: well sounds like you know how to begin then. why don't you try it?